# Why i cant use some button with some game with usb controller?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb-on-the-go, game-controllers

I bought a USB controller called 'ShanWan USB WirelassGamepad'. The controller claims to supports all the games but when I try to play '[Real Racing 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.r3_row)' and '[Fractal Combat X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mangopub.fractalcombatx)', I can use *just* the Analog Stick(or D Pad) but I cant use other buttons.

<sup>I'm using Galaxy Note 2, Android 4.4.2 If it's relevant</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not all games have full gamepad support.  Manufacturers of these gamepads will claim that every game is supported which is only half true.  They will only have limited functionality.  I have the exact same issue on certain games using a [G910](http://www.geekbuying.com/item/NEW-G910-Wireless-Bluetooth-Gamepad-Game-Controller-for-Android-TV-BOX-Mini-PC-Smartphone-Tablet-PC---IOS-supported-318373.html) I purchased from geekbuying.

Here is a site that I use to check for full gamepad support.

[Android Gamepad support](http://androidgamepadgames.com/games?tid=1&sort_by=title&sort_order=ASC)